# Python regex - match starting from numeric character

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input

```
abc-preview-check-random-post-5.500.510-5009
abc-preview-check-random-post-2.15.510-50098709
```

Expected output:

```
5.500.510-5009
2.15.510-50098709
```

I tried `[^a-zA-z]` but its matching the dashes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working regex could be: `\d.*$`

```py
import re
p = re.compile('\d.*$')
p.findall("abc-preview-check-random-post-5.500.510-5009")
# ['5.500.510-5009']
p.findall("abc-preview-check-random-post-2.15.510-50098709")
# ['2.15.510-50098709']
```

Comment: thats nice and simple.. thanks a lot..